# Excel Nominal and Effect in Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have Nominal and Effect function in excel for Calculating Quarterly Rate,

```
      =NOMINAL(EFFECT('10.60%',4),12)
```

So how do i Calculate Quarterly Rate in Jquery or is there function for Nominal or Effect in Jquery

what i found after googling

```
     NOMINAL(effect_rate, npery)
```

Idk why i'm not able to upload image here its link
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/4M2jz.png

i think Nominal Rate will 10.60% and NpQuery will 4 am i right?

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/NOMINAL-function-7f1ae29b-6b92-435e-b950-ad8b190ddd2b

Answer (score 1):

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/NOMINAL-function-7f1ae29b-6b92-435e-b950-ad8b190ddd2b

if someone is finding the Formula for Nominal and Effect here its

```
         Nominal=NOMINAL(effect_rate, npery)
         $Effect=pow((1+($nominal_rate/$npquery)),$npquery)-1;
         $nominal_rate=(sqrt($Effect+1)-1)*$npquery;
```

Answer (score 0):

now you can use these functions to calculate Nominal and effect value like excel functions

```
  function NOMINAL(effect_rate, npery) {
   npery = parseInt(npery);
   if ((effect_rate <= 0) || (npery < 1)) return null;
   nominal = npery * Math.pow(1 + effect_rate, 1 / npery) - npery;
   return (isFinite(nominal) ? nominal: null);
 }


function effect(rate, npery){
    npery = parseInt(npery);
    if (( npery == 0 ) || ( rate == 0 )){ return(0); }
    rate = eval((rate)/(100));
    effect_value = ((Math.pow(1 + (rate/npery), npery)) - 1) * 100;
    return (effect_value);
}
```